# Why am I gettting cannot find symbol error? I'm blind/learning Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sublist

```
import java.util.*;
public class centeredAverage {
    public static void main(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     max = Math.max(max, nums[i]);
    }
    int min = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      min = Math.min(min, nums[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] == max) {
        nums = nums.subList(0, nums[i]) + nums.sublist(nums[i]+1, nums.length);
    }
      if (nums[i] == min) {
        nums = nums.subList(0, nums[i]) + nums.sublist(nums[i]+1, nums.length);
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      count += nums[i];
    }
   return count/nums.length;
}
```

The error is on line number 16:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol:   method subList(int,int)
>
> location: variable nums of type int[]

Comment: `nums` is an `int`-array. Arrays in Java do not define methods. Thus you cannot call `subList(...)` on an array. Even if the code would work, `subList(...)` suggests that a `List<...>` is returned, not an array.

Comment: What can I do in order to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I do not know because I do not know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You first run **subList** and next **sublist**, the error refers to lower-case **sublist**. JAVA compiler is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined "nums" as an array of integer values: `int[] nums`. Anywhere that you reference `nums`, the compiler will only allow you to do things that are valid for an integer array.

For example, this would be allowed:

```
int len = nums.length;
```

But this would not – because `.subList()` is not something you can call on an array:

```
nums = nums.subList(...);
```

In order to extract a part of an array, you could use [Arrays.copyOfRange()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-), like this:

```
int[] partOfNums = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding `nums` is an array which don't have that method.

Answer (score -1):

Try with eclipse ide or any ide..you will get compile error for using nums.sublist..bcoz array dont have methods